Request Permission on PWA (Angular)
I am trying to use Notification.requestPermission().then( in order to get the permission to send over push notification via Firebase cloud messaging.
Right now, when I try to use the above command, my app will blank out the page. The more I search, the more I find people that provide the user with a custom "Accept notifications" button to avoid the pop up that the browser has (PWA on phone does not have a pop up as I see)
Anyone encountered the same issue?
How did you resolve it?
Only thing I tried was initiating the Notification.requestPermission directly from my app component to no results
